# How to fetch multiple column from mysql using go lang

Tags: mysql, web, go

I am trying to fetch multiple columns in a mysql database using the **go** language. Currently I could modify this script, and it would work perfectly well for just fetching one column, and printing it using the http print function. However, when it fetches two things the script no longer works. I don't have any idea what I need to do to fix it. I know that the sql is fine as I have tested that out in the mysql terminal, and it has given me the expected result that I wanted.

```
 conn, err := sql.Open("mysql", "user:password@tcp(localhost:3306)/database")
 statement, err := conn.Prepare("select first,second from table") 
 rows, err := statement.Query()
 for rows.Next() {
         var first string
         rows.Scan(&first)
         var second string
         rows.Scan(&second)
         fmt.Fprintf(w, "Title of first is :"+first+"The second is"+second)
 }
 conn.Close()
```

Comment: What is the "http print function"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using the wrong variable names but I assume that's just a "typo" in your sample code.

Then the correct syntax is:

```
var first, second string
rows.Scan(&first, &second)
```

See [this](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Passing_arguments_to_..._parameters) on what `Scan(dest ...interface{})` means and how to use it.

You should also handle and not ignore the errors.

Finally, you should use [Fprintf](http://golang.org/pkg/fmt/#Fprintf) as it's intended:

```
fmt.Fprintf(w, "Title of first is : %s\nThe second is: %s", first, second)
```

Comment: See https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/ - they are format specifiers and common to most C-based languages.